# Unable to update Git Repo while doing a git pull

Tags: git

I get the following error message while doing the git pull.

git pull
error: unable to create file promo/cnbc/tertiary/1514030668251Paras HMRI Patna - Award Nomination Dec\'17.pdf: No such file or directory
Updating 5235af444..b1462b7b9
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDmd7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to create the folder `promo/cnbc/tertiary/` check to see if this directory tree exists, if not create it and try again. You can also run cmd as administrator (if windows) before running git pull. If Linux/Unix use `sudo git pull`.

Edit: Did you previously delete this PDF?

Comment: Yes. I had deleted this pdf because it contained unrecognized characters in windows.

Comment: That`s why it's unable to create the file. I suggest you download the file from remote separately and then delete it on the remote. Then pull and add the file and commit again. By unrecognized characters, do you mean within the pdf ?

Comment: I'll try to delete it from remote location. Even tried to do a git pull as an admin but it gave the same message.

Comment: Do you not need the file tracked?

Comment: I don't need the file to be tracked as file is corrupted.

Comment: Ok cool, you can either delete it from remote or commit your local changes so the deletion is tracked